# openPojo not picking up parameterized constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm using openPojo to test my getter and setters, it doesn't seem to cover parameterized constructors though.

Trying to reach 100% coverage, so this is a bit vexing.

I've searched this a bit and can't find any solutions, or a explination for it not covering them, but I am a novice with openPojo, so maybe there is something I can add to the validator to force it to pick up these constructors, or maybe there is a reason it can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.pojo.pl/comparison/#precondtioions) site that would suggest that it is not possible to cover constructors with openPojo

I'll leave this question open for a while in the hope somebody know's a workaround / that source is wrong.